# If statement within while loop (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to run the following MATLAB code but a problem occurs. The two lines below the 'while statement':

```
theta_test = theta - alpha_step*abs(grad_th); % linear descent 
[log_marglik_test,grad_th_test] = log_marg(theta_test,grad_th,x,y,n);
```

keep iterating, but I want the whole piece of code to keep cycling until (testy > 0.5 && alpha_step > 0.1).

It appears the program is 'stuck' cycling between the second and third line and never actually reaches the 'if statement'. If anyone can help it will be much appreciated!

```
while (testy > 0.5 && alpha_step > 0.1)
    theta_test = theta - alpha_step*abs(grad_th); % linear descent 
    [log_marglik_test,grad_th_test] = log_marg(theta_test,grad_th,x,y,n);
    % strong wolfe conditions
    if (log_marglik_test <= log_marglik - c1*alpha_step*(grad_th'*grad_th)) && (abs(grad_th_test'*grad_th) <= c2*abs(grad_th'*grad_th))
        theta = theta_test; testy = 0;
    else
        alpha_step = alpha_step * tau;

    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the function `log_marg` ends correctly? Have you debugged your code and check if `log_marg` functions behaves as you expected? It is impossible to know what is happening without details...

Comment: alpha_step = alpha_step * tau; should have plus instead of times perhaps

Comment: are you sure the `if` statement is *never* reached? Have you tried putting an `fprintf` statement inside your `if` block for debugging purposes?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I assumed `alpha_step` is a large number and tau is a multiplier in the [0,1] range. The main point is we know nothing about the problem. I don't see how OP expects anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Yes, log_marg works correctly. If I run each line individually in the command window they work as expected. I am thinking that there must be something wrong with my syntax but I can't find anything online. It's as if MATLAB treats the if statement as the end of the while statement?

Comment: There is no bug in MATLABs if-statement nor while-statement. I would recommend you to use the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) or printouts to findout which statement that fails. you can be fairly certain that either `if` or `else` is executed. However the result may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in one the line with the `if` statement, the loop will pause there if it is getting to the if statement.

Comment: It should reach either if or else, but you use testy > 0.5, and you change testy in if part, and use  alpha_step > 0.1 and you modify alpha_step in else part. This is not good practice to change the control variable of while and  the result is in-predictable. what about while (0 >0.5) && .... , it will exit while. Modify the logic of while to keep the control variable consistent in the loop. and use printout to trace your variables.